# use regex to find a block of text that does not contains a string

Tags: regex

I have a large file that I need to find when a tag is absent from certain blocks. For example-

```
begin
test
stuff here
1234
end

begin
other stuff
key
end
```

I would like to find each begin-end section that does not contain the `key` field. So in this example I would match on the first begin-end section but not the second.

I was able to match each section using `begin(.|\n)+?end` but I couldn't figure out how to only match the sections without the `key` in it. I was reading about backreferences but I couldn't figure out how to use those in this situation either.

Comment: IMHO this doesn't seem like a good use case for regular expressions... Unless you're required to use them, I'd stick with simple string comparison: that would make for clearer code and much simpler logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a negative lookahead is supported, you could check the lines following begin do not match end or key.

```
^begin\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!end|.*\bkey\b).*)*\r?\nend$
```

- `^` Start of line
- `begin\b.*` Match begin, then any char except newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!end|.*\bkey\b).*` Match line that does not start with end or contains key
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\nend` Match end
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMKjuU/1)

If end and key are the only words in the line you could use:

```
^begin.*(?:\r?\n(?!(?:end|key)$).*)*\r?\nend$
```